# Llaves, su funcionamiento - JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, gulp

Que hay compañeros. Estudiando gulp me surgió la interrogante sobre el porque de esta sintaxis

```js
const {series} = require("gulp");
// blabla
// y luego
exports.saludo = series(task1, task2);
```

me refiero a porque const **{** series **}** = require("gulp"). Según tengo entendido las llaves se utilizan para establecer un ámbito o bien para crear la estructura de un objeto, pero vendría del lado derecho del signo =. Obviamente estoy al tanto de que si no lo hago así, el método "series" no estara definido. ¿Pero por qué?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: El uso de las llaves de esa forma, es para hacer referencia a una función u objeto de dicho de modulo. Para no tener que estar repitiendo código y así simplificar tu código, y darle un toque mas limpio y organizado

Comment: Aquí viene un ejemplo que te ayudará a entender dicha sintaxis [doc. oficial modules en NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como sabemos JavaScript tiene un tipo de dato llamado objeto ( esto pertenece a una técnica de programación llamada poo u oop en ingles ) y ese tipo de dato se compone de propiedades y métodos, pero no siempre necesitamos utilizar todo lo que en ese objeto esta encapsulado porque simplemente utilizaremos una propiedad o un método entonces declaramos una variable y la igualamos a la propiedad que queremos para eso utilizaremos la “notación punto”

```
var miPropiedad = objeto.propiedadDelObjeto;
```

simple, pero tedioso cuando son muchas cosas las que tenemos que utilizar (pero aun no las suficientes para utilizar todo el objeto)

```
var miPropiedad = objeto.propiedadDelObjeto;
var miPropiedad2 = objeto.propiedadDelObjeto2;
var miMetodo = objeto.metodoDelObjeto;
```

ademas estoy escribiendo muchas lineas que parecerían estar haciendo lo mismo para solucionar esto el estándar [es6](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=es6&t=canonical&atb=v1-1&ia=web) nos da otro tipo de notación llamada [destructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment) ( como su nombre indica divide ) y esta nos facilita la vida por que todo lo podemos escribir en una linea pura azúcar sintáctica, también es mas fácil de leer otra gran ventaja es que también podemos utilizarla con arreglos

```
var  { miPropiedad, miPropiedad2, miMetodo }  = objeto;
```

Comment: De hecho en JS excepto los datos primitivos, todos los demás son considerados objetos